# Deleting Core Data object but it still shows up in NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am writing a time tracking app in Swift, and I have a problem with deleting a time spent on an activity. My delete function hides it from tableView on 2 views and appears to remove it from **Core Data**, but the time doesn’t delete from my "total hours spent today" function.

Code for deleting from history. This works for tableView in two different view controllers:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let historyToDelete = fetchController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let todaysActivitiesArray = CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.fetchCoreDataForTodayActivities()
        let main = MainViewController()
        var totalDuration = main.calculateTotalDurationForToday()
        let historyDel = fetchController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! History
        totalDuration = totalDuration - Int(historyDel.duration!)
        CoreDataHandler.sharedInstance.deleteObject(historyToDelete as! NSManagedObject)
        main.totalduration = totalDuration

        }
}
```

Code for getting today Activity array:

```
 func fetchCoreDataForTodayActivities() -> [History] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("History", inManagedObjectContext: self.backgroundManagedObjectContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

    let dateDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDate", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateDescriptor]

    let startDate = NSDate.dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay()
    let endDate = NSDate.dateByMovingToEndOfDay()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(startDate >= %@) AND (startDate <= %@)", startDate, endDate)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    return (fetchCoreDataWithFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [History])
}
```

Code for calculating today's activity:

```
func calculateTotalDurationForToday() -> NSInteger {
    var sumOfDuration = 0
    for history in todaysActivitiesArray {
        sumOfDuration += (history.duration?.integerValue)!
    }
    return sumOfDuration
}
```

If I close the simulator and run again the total time subtracts as expected, so the deletion must not be triggered until I close it. Please help, I've been stuck on this a while now.

Comment: You might save the context to commit the deletion and `main` is a brand new instance of `MainViewController` rather than the expected one in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As @vadian notes, your core problem is that `main` is completely independent of anything you put on the screen. You create a view controller, modify it, and then throw it away.

Your `MainViewController` should observe Core Data and modify itself when the data changes. That will cause it to update as you expect.